# Sort array returned by ActiveRecord by date (or any other column)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

How can I sort an array returned by an ActiveRecord query by a `created_at` date column?

This occurs once the query has been executed.

Please don't tell me to do it in the query because I need this to happen in the view.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Ruby includes support for sorting out of the box.

```
sorted = @records.sort_by &:created_at
```

However, this doesn't appear to have much to do with display and probably belongs in the controller.

Comment: Enumerable#sort_by is great for this sort of thing, much better than the other example with Enumerable#sort.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I've got multiple "entry points" to the same view, and the queries may or may not have the same sorting patterns (i know, not ideal). But isn't the order in which lists of stuff will be displayed not necessarily a "controller-only" feature?

Comment: tadman - care to elaborate? It's my understanding from the api docs that sort_by is the slower, more flexible, way of doing a sort. Great for more complex sorts, but too much for something this simple.

Comment: @Bill D: That's pretty much opposite to the truth. `sort` is more flexible — you specify the entire comparison predicate, whereas with `sort_by` you just tell it *what* to compare and it does it using the default `sort` predicate. This case, where you call a method and sort based on the result, is quite common — `sort_by` is just a more concise way of writing that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to go back and figure out how I misunderstood - I'm pretty sure I got the quick green checkmark, at any rate, only because I reluctantly obeyed his wish that I not berate him about doing this in the view.

Comment: If the list is inherently ordered that should be encapsulated in the model. Other than that, the order in which to display the records properly belongs in the view or in the view model, not the controller.

Comment: @BillD appears to be right, though.  `sort_by` is more expensive for simple keysets, because of the Schwartzian transform, see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Comment: @Eero The docs says: `As of Ruby 1.8, the method Enumerable#sort_by implements a built-in Schwartzian Transform, useful when key computation or comparison is expensive.` which indicates that in the case mentioned you ought to use `sort_by` instead of `sort`. Because Schwartzian transform is less slow than the normal `sort`. That's why it's a note under the `sort` method.

Comment: @Magne, you very well quote that the Schwartzian transform is useful when `key computation or comparison is expensive`, but note also that `This makes sort_by fairly expensive when the keysets are simple`. In the case of `created_at`, a date column, we are dealing with a very simple keyset. Key computation is not needed (we already have the date value that is the sort key) and the comparison is not expensive (simple numeric comparison is sufficient for ordering dates). Hence the Schwartzian transform (with its extra array) is a waste of resources, compared to the more straightforward `sort`.

Comment: @Eero That's true, I agree. For some reason my Chrome jumps up to the sort method whenever I click the link you gave, so I saw that as a backing of your point, which seemed like a misunderstanding. I see now that your link actually goes to the `sort_by` method, which has the info you just mentioned, that backs up really using `sort` instead of `sort_by` in this case.

Comment: How do you specify `DESC` with this syntax?

Answer (score 39):

While Ruby [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html) is awesome, ActiveRecord queries will actually return an ActiveRecord::Relation whose query will not have been evaluated yet (Lazy Loading) and can have the order method called on it to off-load this processing to the database where it will scale much better than an [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html) based strategy.

Using Enumerable for sorting also confounds doing pagination in the database.  There is nothing to prevent the order strategy from being applied in the view.  However, I would tend to put this in scope on the model.

```
sorted = @records.order(:created_at)
```

Answer (score 26):

Just call sort on the collection, passing in the block of code which tells Ruby how you want it to sort:

```
collection.sort { |a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```

Comment: This is way too inefficient compared to `.sort_by` in this case. Please check the other answer by Chuck.

Comment: For the record, this will be no less efficient than the version I gave.

Comment: For the record, this will be more efficient for a simple sort key such as a datetime - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Comment: Best answer, sometimes you want to look at the long form. Mostly efficiency doesn't matter, thats why we're all writing ruby.

Answer (score 13):

Please look at this one and also check complexities.

```
Model.all.sort_by{|m| m.created_at} #=> O(log n)

#versus

Model.order(“created_at DESC”) #=> O(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the runtime complexity O(log n) and O(1)

Comment: if not indexed in db bot are O(log n), but one will run in DB other in code

Answer (score 5):

The best way sorting ActiveRecord array is using default method order

> @users.order(:created_at)

It's the quickest and the most right solution, because in that case it returns sorted array from db and you no need to use any other operation for that in the Class, for example if you will use suggested `sort_by` it will loop throw each element of array, and after that it won't be an ActiveRecord array, not cool in my opinion.

`order` can use strings and sumbols, it's very useful, and it takes multiple parameters

> @users.order('created_at asc, first_name desc, last_name asc')