# How do I group content according to date (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to group contents that belong on a same date together for display, such that the date only gets posted once and in chronological order.

Something like:

**14th October 2009**
Item 3
Item 3 content

Item 2
Item 2 content

**13th October 2009**
Item 1
Item 3 content

How can I display that in view? (Assume that @items is being passed from the controller, which contains all the items)

I've tried group_by, but I can't get it to work as it seems to be arranging itself by the value of the day itself rather than together with the month.

The code in question: http://github.com/davidchua/Political-Watch/blob/master/app/views/items/index.html.erb

To see the problem in a live deployment, its at http://political-watch.org

Comment: This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278510/sort-array-returned-by-activerecord-by-date-or-any-other-column

Comment: Whenever I see 'sort/group by date' I think ISO8601 date format, but it's not as popular as it *should* be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Replace the line 5 of app/controllers/items_controller.rb with:

```
  @items = Item.all(:order => "date DESC")
```

2) Replace line 3-14 of app/views/items/index.html.erb with:

```
<%  date = 1.day.from_now(@items.first.date.to_date) rescue nil # increment the day
    @items.each do |item| 
      if date > item.date.to_date 
        date = item.date.to_date %>
        <div style="background: #81BEF7;margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" class="rounded"><b><span style="padding: 5px"><%=h date %></span></b></div>
      <%end%>

      <p>
        <i><%=h item.time %> - </i>
         <%= link_to "#{item.title}", item.link %><br>
        <a href="/items/<%=item.id%>"><span class="subtext" style="margin-left: 55px">by <%= item.user.username %> | <%=item.comments.count%> comments </span></a>
    </p>

<%  end # end for items_each%>
```

In this approach you are using the DB for sorting and a simple comparison for grouping.

PS: I don't think it is a good idea to name your database columns as 'date'. In some of the databases 'date' is a reserved keyword.

Comment: This seems to be just right, but how do I just compare the dates (day, month, year) without the time because if an item is posted just one minute or one second after the previous item, it will generate a new date header for it.

Comment: The call: 'item.date.to_date' prunes the time part from the 'datetime' field. So you should see the rows grouped by date rather than date-time.

Comment: E.g.: Check this example:
k = (1..10).collect{|i| Time.now + (i*3).hours}; p k; j = k.collect {|d| d.to_date}; p j                    Look at the two arrays printed. First one has the time part and the second one does not.

Comment: Thanks!

I think I've fixed that small little bug in that code, date should be:

date = item.date.to_date in line #4

It works perfectly now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 29):

```
items.group_by{ |item| item.created_at.to_date }
```

Comment: Amazing! - `What kind of sorcery is this?`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following migration:

```
class AddIndexToItemsStartDate < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :items, :start_date
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
@items = Item.where("start_date >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
@items_by_day = @items.group_by { |t| t.start_date.beginning_of_day }
```

View with nice display:

```
<% @items_by_day.sort.each do |day, items| %>
<h2><%= day.strftime("%d %B %Y") %></h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th></th>           
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <% for item in items %>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.item_id %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Delete', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>
```