# Ruby on Rails: Items by date, with date as header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create the following HTML table in Rails 7:

|  | Dec-20 | Dec-21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 2 | 4 |
| Item2 | 3 | 5 |

The data is stored in a normalized way:

| date | item | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dec-20 | Item1 | 2 |
| Dec-21 | Item1 | 4 |

This seems to be a fairly straightforward use case but I have not found a good example or tool explaining how to do this, either in the controller or in HTML.
These articles give a partial explanation:
[How to group events objects under a single shared date with group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192463/how-to-group-events-objects-under-a-single-shared-date-with-group-by?rq=1)
[How do I group content according to date (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581667/how-do-i-group-content-according-to-date-rails)
Any guidance would be appreciated. Particularly if there is a tool, similar to Chartkick that automates this process.
Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way I've find in the past has been to get a unique list of dates, and a unique list of items, as ordered arrays, and get all the values as a hash, and loop through the unique items and unique days and output the matches in the table ... If this works, I can give examples in an answer if you can post some code from your models

Comment: Thank you @Jad As I mentioned earlier, the database table is stored as noted above. This is what I have so far in the HTML (nothing in the controller)   `<table>
    <% @cf = company_facts.group_by(&:date) %>
      <% @cf.each_pair do |date, item| %>
        <th><%= date %></th>
      <% end %>
      <% @cf.each_pair do |date, item| %>
        <% item.each do |list| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= list.name %></td>
            <td><%= list.value %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>`

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the code blocks? It'll make it easier to read, and I'll try to fix what I can.  Can you include code from your controller as well as your view?

Comment: @Jad Apologies, this is only my thrid question. I tried to following the format guidelines but it won't let me indent the code

Comment: Yes, you can't format comments. You need to edit your original question to put code blocks in. I'll see what I can do with what you've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that doing the work in the controller makes the view less complicated:

assumption that your company_facts model has the following structure:

```
"id" integer
"cat_id" references category (id)
"date" of type date
"name" string (which is the "item")
"value" number (to be displayed in the table)
```

Controller:

```
def index

  @cf = company.company_facts.where(cat_id: cat_id)
  @dates = @cf.map(&:date).uniq.sort
  @items = @cf.map(&:name).uniq.sort
  @hash = Hash.new(0)
  @cf.each_with_object(@hash) {|obj,hsh| hsh[ [obj.date, obj.name] ] = obj.value}

end
```

View (I prefer HAML ... hopefully you can work with this):

```
%table
  %tr
    %td
    - @dates.each do |date|
      %th= date
  - @items.each do |item|
    %tr
      %th= item
      - @dates.each do |date|
        %td= number_with_delimiter( @hash[ [date, item] ] )
```

the most complicated bit in the above is creating the hash, using a key that is a combined array of the date and the item label.  You could do all of the above without creating the hash, by performing lookups against your database for each entry, but if you have a large amount of data to plot, you will find creating the `Hash` to be significantly quicker and lower impact.

by using `Hash.new` we also specify the default return value if there is no match.

I don't know from your example where `company` and `cat_id` are set, so you will need to make sure that that logic also goes into your controller.

Comment: Thank you so very much! This is exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your time and guidance!!!

Comment: In case anyone needs the HTML `<tr>
      <% @dates.each do |date| %>
        <th><td>date</td></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <% @dates.each do |date| %>
          <td><%= number_with_delimiter( @hash[ [date, item] ] ) %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>`

Comment: Thanks. I was doing the opposite, date rows and columns for keys. This solution worked perfectly (once I swiched the tables around)