# Ruby on Rails: how to sort data in an array of active record objects right before iterating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to sort an array of Active Record objects by by a field?

This array is a field of an object, `link_pages`, and I want it sorted by the field "`sequence`"

```
<% @menu_bar.link_pages.each do |lp| %>
                <li id="page_<%= lp.id%>" class="ui-state-default">
                  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>

                  <font size=5><%= lp.name %></font> | 
                  <%= link_to "remove",
                         :controller => "admin/menu_bars",
                         :action => :remove_page_from_menu,
                         :page => lp.id,
                         :id => @menu_bar.id %>
                </li>
          <% end %>
```

Maybe there is a way to do `@menu_bar.link_pages.sort_by_sequence.each do`, which would be slick, but I just don't know.

Comment: version 2.3.8 I think. Def not 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@menu_bar.link_pages.sort_by { |e| e.sequence }.each do |lp|
  . . .
```

Comment: `@menu_bar.link_pages.sort_by &:sequence.each do |lp|` is the shorthand _to_proc_ way. See also [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278510/sort-array-returned-by-activerecord-by-date-or-any-other-column)

Answer (score 2):

Is `link_pages` *really* an array of activerecord objects?

What happens if you add this in the view?

```
<%= debug @menu_bar.link_pages.class %>
```

Two things can happen. It can print "Array" or it can print "ActiverecordThing" (something similar to that, definitively not Array).

If you really have an Array, use DigitalRoss' solution. If you have an "ActiverecordSomething", then, create a [named_scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope), so you can reuse easily:

```
# Assuming that your model name is "Page"
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  named_scope :sorted_by_sequence, :order => 'pages.sequence ASC'
  ...
end
```

Then you can do:

```
<% @menu_bar.link_pages.sorted_by_sequence each do |lp| %>
```